# How to Join the same named columns of different tables

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

Here I describe my issue more simply about what kind of query I need:

Consider that I have three tables AccessPolicy, Document and Term.  Here both the names of the AccessPolicy and the Name of the Document is stored in the “Term” table. I need to return the following fields from the 3 tables. I need to fetch the Name field two time for AccessPolicy and the Document respectively in a single select query.

```
Term.Name as AccessPolicyName
Term.Name as DocumentName
AccessPolicy.TermID
Document.TermID
Document.UserName
AccessPolicy.ValidFrom
```

How to form a select query to return the above result?

I need to do this in Oracle 11g.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You haven't said how the tables are related. Presumably the `TermID` in the `AccessPolicy` and `Document` tables relate to an entry in the `Term` table, perhaps identified by a column called `ID`. But we don't know if you're expecting the same `TermID` in both - so there's a single `Term` record that links the other two tables. Since you're pulling the name twice I'd have thought not, but then there's no indication of how the join *should* be made.

If there are two `TermID` values involved then you need to join to `Term` twice, something like:

```
select t1.Name as AccessPolicyName,
    t2.Name as DocumentName,
    ap.TermID as AccessPolicyTermID,
    d.TermID as DocumentTermID,
    d.UserName,
    ap.ValidFrom
from AccessPolicy ap
join Term t1 on t1.ID = ap.TermID
join Document d on d.someColumn = ap.someColumn -- don't know how policy and document are related?
join Term t2 on t2.ID = d.TermID
```

Comment: Hi Alex, Yes you guess it correctly. I have different TermId for AccessPolicy and Document to link with the Term table. I am able to get the desired result as per your design. Further the document and The AccessPolicy are linked by DocumentID. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

```
select
    Term.Name as AccessPolicyName,
    Term.Name as DocumentName,
    AccessPolicy.TermID,
    Document.TermID,
    Document.UserName,
    AccessPolicy.ValidFrom
from Term t
left join AccessPolicy ap on ap.Name = t.Name
left join Document d on d.Name = t.Name;
```

Note that both AccessPolicy and Document info may be null

Comment: You need to use the alias in the column references in the select, or it'll throw ORA-00904. `t.Name`, `ap.TermID`, etc.